# Making interface accept multiple possibilities

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, types

I am trying to create an interface which will accept all possible options for a passed variable. I want it to be either one object, or the other.

```
export interface OfferActionType {
  type: typeof C.SET_SELECTED_OFFER_ID;
  payload: {count: number} | {selectedId: string | null}; //How do I do this for OfferStateType?
}

export interface OfferStateType {
  count: number;
  selectedId: string | null;
}
```

And here's the calling code:

```
export const rootReducer = (state: OfferStateType = initialState, action: OfferActionType) => {
  const { payload, type } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case C.SET_SELECTED_OFFER_ID:
      return { ...state, selectedId: state.selectedId };
    case C.SET_COUNT:
      return { ...state, count: state.count + payload.count };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Currently I'm getting this error:

> Property 'count' does not exist on type '{ count: number; } | { id: string | null; }'.

Which makes sense. But `payload` might look different for every case. How do I handle this? I can't just make all optional, but doing it this way doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think making a different interfaces for each actions (i.e. `CountAction` and `SelectedIdAction`) and declaring `OfferActionType` as union of them is a better practice. Here is the code:

```
enum C {
  SET_SELECTED_OFFER_ID,
  SET_COUNT,
}

interface ICountAction {
  type: C.SET_COUNT;
  payload: number;
}

interface ISelectedIdAction {
  type: C.SET_SELECTED_OFFER_ID;
  payload: string | null;
}

type OfferAction = ICountAction | ISelectedIdAction;

const countAction: OfferAction = {
  type: C.SET_COUNT,
  payload: 3,
};
const idAction: OfferAction = {
  type: C.SET_SELECTED_OFFER_ID,
  payload: "foobar",
};

const reducer = (action: OfferAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case C.SET_SELECTED_OFFER_ID:
      return console.log(action.payload);
    case C.SET_COUNT:
      return console.log(action.payload);
    default:
      return 0;
  }
};

reducer(countAction);
reducer(idAction);
```

The result is:

```
> 3
> foobar
```

By using the switch-case pattern with a proper `Enum`, the action type will get properly type-casted in each case-branches like below (See how Intellisense recognizes it).
[image: action is type-casted correctly]

If your `C` was just an object with `string` typed fields, all the `OfferAction`s' `type` fields will just be strings, and the compiler will complain that it cannot know what type the `payload` field will be.

```
const C = {
  SET_COUNT: "SET_COUNT",
  SET_SELECTED_OFFER_ID: "SET_SELECTED_OFFER_ID",
};

interface ICountAction {
  type: typeof C.SET_SELECTED_OFFER_ID;
  payload: number;
}

interface ISelectedIdAction {
  type: typeof C.SET_SELECTED_OFFER_ID;
  payload: string | null;
}

// Same below
```

[image: the action did not get type-casted]

Comment: This works after I change `|` to `&` here `type OfferAction = ICountAction | ISelectedIdAction;` Any idea why? Leaving `|` causes the same error as before. Also why type instead of interface?

Comment: Actually I cannot reproduce your claim, since the intersection type (by using `&`) of `ICountAction` and `ISelectedAction` will be `never`. Is `C` proper `Enum` or just an object with lots of field? In order to make my solution work, the `C` type you introduced should be an `Enum`, to make the compiler properly guess the type of each actions. (Possible candidates for `OfferAction` types should be defined uniquely by checking the type of `action.type` field). And I used `type` keyword because `Interface` keyword does not support `Union types`, i.e. the use of `|` operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
export interface OfferActionType {
  type: typeof C.SET_SELECTED_OFFER_ID;
  payload: OfferStateType;
}

export interface OfferStateType {
  count?: number;
  selectedId?: string | null;
}
```

Try it.

Comment: This will work, but make them optional. And I was curious if it's possible to set either one of them as mandatory

Comment: you mean, it could have at least one props?

Comment: It should have precisely one of these props. Changing it to `payload: {count: number} & {selectedId: string | null};` seems to solve the problem but I have no idea why

Comment: I think you already know the answer. 
`{ count: number; } | { id: string | null; }` Try to change `id` => `selectedId`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACACogngGwPaIAmA3sGhWgA44HEBcaZlLay+ArlI+BwLYAjOGnKUAvmgA+TUazSgijAM6RYEAOZS0vXLlloxwQ8HbgV1HIyx5CRNAF4mIljRsMZciuy6RGARn1DMQBuE3wzSAtsACYrWlsHJ31XOkUPTwVGAHIVWCzAo1CwiKiAZji3O0cSZ0oU20ZmDLSc1SyAGn0Wb240aIKQ4vNXABYK1MSa5Pj3JrlM7Q5dTs82Tl7+liDQoA

Comment: The type was part of the problem, right. But the problem is I can assign it like in the playground. But when I try to do the math, as in the question, it fails. It works after I change the `|` to `&`. Any idea why?